# Bootstrap: Is there a way to get a tighter layout?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Just curious if there is a way to get a tighter layout with bootstrap.

Why is there so much space between the text elements?
[image: too much space]

Is it all just to accomodate pads, phones, etc?

Is there any way to choose a tighter style for the entire page to default to?

I also think the edit boxes themsselves are too large.  There is too much wasted space between the text and the edge of the box.

Why aren't they a bit tighter?

---

---

**These edits have been added after attempting to use code in answer from NetworkNerd**

I have added the following to my stylesheet.

```
  input[type=text]{
       padding-top:0px; padding-bottom:0px;
       margin-bottom:0px; /* Reduced from whatever it currently is */
       margin-top:0px; /* Reduced from whatever it currently is */
       height:24px;
    }
```

Those additions make my form look like the following:

[image: doesn't quite work]

You can see that things got a bit tighter, but that is only because of the `height:24px` style.

The other changes do not seem to have any affect on the look.

By the way, the stylesheet which includes this change is the last one included.

**Labels Are Not Aligned**

Also, notice that now that I've changed that the labels are not aligned with their associated text input.

**Still Too Much Margin Between Text Boxes**

And there still seems to be too much margin space between the text boxes.

**HTML Code Snippet For Title**

Here's a snippet of the HTML which shows the HTML with the applied Bootstrap styles.
This was all just copied from samples on the bootstrap site.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="titleText" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Title</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input id="titleText" class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="book.title" />
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: The people who created Bootstrap like air.

Comment: I have a single word to describe it: Minimalism. Actually, let's add another: Flat.

Comment: Aibrean, NetworkNerd - so you guys are with me on this, right?  The default layout is too fat. So much of bootstrap is easily customizable. I just wonder why they didn't make a skinny option.

Comment: That's what [LESS customization](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) is for. They made the customization area so you could put in your own values for a tailored CSS output. They included padding there (`@input-height-base`).

Comment: @daylight Yeah, I agree. But keep in mind, Twitter Bootstrap isn't meant to be "set it and forget it". It's designed **to be a template for customization**.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I can accept that.  It's just my misunderstanding and lack of experience with bootstrap that made me feel that way.  Thanks for the great feedback, all.

Comment: @daylight -- Take a look at my answer, it might provide you with an option that could avoid using extra CSS

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Bootstrap doesn't recommend editing `bootstrap.css` itself. It is recommended per best practices to modify the bootstrap style in another, dominant CSS file.

Try doing something like this:

### Custom CSS

```
input[type=text]{
   padding:0px;
   margin-bottom:2px; /* Reduced from whatever it currently is */
   margin-top:2px; /* Reduced from whatever it currently is */
}
```

It's hard to tell from the picture if it's a margin on the top or bottom. You can remove the `margin-[top|bottom]` based on what the result of your testing is.

**It's also possible** that the `input` element isn't the one with a margin, it could be the `label` element instead (Bootstrap, at least in my experiences, does some strange things with the `label` element...)

Another edit: I like to give people options. Therefore, if this is in a `table` element, consider adding the `table-condensed` class to the `table` tag to reduce some of the whitespace between items, as shown below:

```
<table class="table table-condensed">
```

Comment: I can confirm that this will work, as this is what I use in my (non Twitter Bootstrap) website login form.

Comment: I'm working with this now and testing it.  This is a great example to get me going in the right direction. After I work with it I'll come back later or in a day or two and mark it as the answer.  Thanks again.

Comment: I added a native solution in my answer. You can use `form-control-sm` in Bootstrap 4, or `input-sm` in Bootstrap 3.

Answer (score 0):

In Bootstrap 4 you can use the `form-control-sm` class. See https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/forms/#sizing

This is taken directly from the Bootstrap documentation,

```
<input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" placeholder=".form-control-sm">
```

Prior to Bootstrap 4 you could use `input-sm`. See https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#forms-control-sizes

Answer (score -2):

You can go into the bootstrap.css and find the padding and margin values and change them around or do that in another stylesheet

Comment: muuk - That sounds so painful.  Have you done this yourself?  Just curious. I would definitely create it as a seperate CSS so I could react to bootstrap versioning. Wonder how much I'd have to override. Thanks.

Comment: It's best to use a separate stylesheet -- overriding the default file can create complications in the long run.

Comment: I would never do that. As other say just override the style.

Comment: I said you could do it in another stylesheet guys, calm down

Comment: I guess because I was lazy but I do agree I should have to prevent confusion